# Issue with browser zoom in Flex app

Tags: java, actionscript-3, apache-flex, browser

We have an issue with our Flex application. It has Flex UI component and a backend java component.
When the browser is zoomed to more than 100%, application becomes completely frozen (no component not even scroll bar responds).

Am new to Flex, any pointers to fix this issue would be really helpful.

-------UPDATE

Actuallly I figured out that problem occurs when invalidateProperties function is called on UIComponent.as for one of our custom components.
If I comment this call, it works all fine.Any idea?
------- UPDATE2

setDataList method makes a call to invalidateProperties which trigger commitProperties. Issue happens @ the line

```
          vboxContainer.addChild(checkBox);
```

in commitProperties function.

Below is the code for setDataList and commitProperties.

```
    public function set dataList(value:ArrayCollection):void{
            //_dataList = value;
            _dataList = ObjectUtil.copy(value) as ArrayCollection;
            dataListChanged = true;
            invalidateProperties();
        }

    override protected function commitProperties():void{
            super.commitProperties();
            if(dataListChanged){
                vboxContainer.removeAllChildren();
                for each(var itemLabel:VO in _dataList){
                    var checkBox:MultilineCheckBox = new MultilineCheckBox();
                    checkBox.label = itemLabel.principleName;
                    checkBox.selected = itemLabel.checked;
                    /*checkBox.setStyle("paddingBottom",0);
                    checkBox.setStyle("paddingTop",0);
                    checkBox.setStyle("verticalGap",0);
                    checkBox.setStyle("fontSize",10); */
                    //checkBox.setStyle("height",10);   
                    //checkBox.setStyle("width",700); 
                    checkBox.width = 850;
                    checkBox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, updateSelectedValues);
                    vboxContainer.addChild(checkBox);
                }
                dataListChanged = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Not much to go on. What does your component do?

Comment: Do you have any resize handlers in your application?  My gut reaction (all I have to go on given the total lack of detail here!) is that you might have an infinite loop with resize functions.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I see the problem is rectified if I remove one of the mxml files used within the screen. Am not sure what exactly is wrong with that particular mxml. There is no resize function used anywhere.

Comment: The code of this component might be helpful. When calling invalidateProperties, do you reset the changed flag in commitProperties ?

Comment: Thanks @philarmon In commitProperties function, If dataList is changed, it removes the existing child components and adds them from the dataList. and set dataChanged = false;

Comment: Just updated my question with the code. thanks.

Comment: If it freezes at the line where you add the checkbox it might be something wrong with the checkbox component or some outside containers that are resized in a loop when you add a new component here, really hard to say from this code snippet. And you have a small memory leak here - when you remove old checkboxes you should loop trough and remove the evet listener from them, otherwise they will stay in the memory forever